# What does return this in Function.prototype.method do?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I just started reading JavaScript: The Good Parts and I'm already confused by what 'return this' does in Function.prototype.method? I understand how 'this' and 'return' works. 'this' is essentially a pointer for the current object and 'return' simply exits the function while outputting a value if you described any; in our case, 'this'.

Here's the code I'm referencing to.

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
}

/* SIMPLE CONSTRUCTOR */
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

/* ADD METHODS */
Person.method('getName', function() { return this.name; });
Person.method('getAge', function() { return this.age; });

var rclark = new Person('Ryan Clark', 22);

console.log(rclark.getName()); // string(Ryan Clark)
console.log(rclark.getAge()); // number(22)
```

I tried omitting 'return this' to see if the code would break but it doesn't? What exactly does 'return this' do? I'll keep progressing through this book but I want to make sure I'm understanding everything. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allows for chaining so you can do something like this:

```
/* ADD METHODS */
Person.method('getName', function() { return this.name; })
      .method('getAge', function() { return this.age; });
```

Comment: Simple A++ explanation! So like how jQuery works in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

`return this` returns the object on which `method()` was called, and after it has been modified by adding the passed method to it.

Omitting it won't break your code, but it is a better style that allows chained method invocation, so you can for instance:

```
Person.method('getName', function() { return this.name; }).method('getAge', function() { return this.age; });
```

Comment: I never really thought of this. Is it something that will be explained later on in the book? If 'return this' was omitted however and you tried chaining, it'd break your code because you'd be tring to chain onto nothing.

Comment: @W3Geek I don't know if is explained later in the book, but I learned this from experience.